# TikZ---reading coordinates from an external file

Tags: tikz-pgf, directlua

I am trying to draw a picture with inputs from a bunch of csv files.

Let's take the case where the content of the file is a simple tuple of floats:

```
>>> cat coords/right_corner.csv
8.000000000000000000e+00,-8.856910857039457241e-01
```

I wrote a lua script to read it, add bracket and print it:

```lua
-- parse.lua
local M = {}


function M.coordinate(rpath)
    file = io.open(rpath, "r")
    tex.print(string.format([[(%s)]], file:read()))
    -- print(string.format([[(%s)]], file:read()))
    file:close()
end


return M
```

I want to draw a vertical line, of a given length, whose top is at these coordinates.
I then want to add nodes along that vertical line (1/3 and 2/3, or 1/4, 1/2 and 3/4).
I thought the first thing I would have to do is to save the coordinates stored in the file as a TikZ coordinate object, so I could reference it later.

A corresponding LaTeX very minimal WE would be

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[border=3pt, tikz, 12pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\tikzmath{%
    \H = 3;
}
\directlua{parse = require('parse')}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % breaks
        \coordinate (rightCorner) at \directlua{parse.coordinate('coords/right_corner.csv')};
        % \coordinate (rightCorner) at (8.000000000000000000e+00,-8.856910857039457241e-01)
        %     ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this breaks (`mwe.tikz|| Runaway argument?`). My understanding is that it should evaluate to the two commented lines underneath, which run fine.

If instead I replace the content of the `tikzpicture` block by `\draw[dotted, black] \directlua{parse.coordinate('coords/left_corner.csv')} -- ++(0,-\H);` it builds OK, but the pdf output is blank. Again, substituting the `\directlua` bit by the expected output of the file, i.e. hard-coding the coordinates, works fine.

```
\draw[dotted, black] (8.000000000000000000e+00,-8.856910857039457241e-01)
    -- ++(0,-\H);
```

What am I missing? I have used a similar construct to loop over lines in a file, to draw more complicated shapes, where the `lua` function is simply

```lua
for line in io.lines(rpath) do --single_floe.csv') do
    tex.print(string.format([[(%s) -- ]], line))
end
```

with an additional `cycle` in the `tex` source, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have no idea why, but removing the parentheses print from the lua script and bracing the call to `directlua` with parentheses instead yields the expected result:

```lua
local M = {}


function M.coordinate(rpath)
    file = io.open(rpath, "r")
    tex.print(file:read())
    file:close()
end


return M
```

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[border=3pt, tikz, 12pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{math}

\tikzmath{%
    \H = 3;
}

\directlua{parse = require('parse')}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (rightCorner) at (\directlua{parse.coordinate('coords/right_corner.csv')});
        \draw (rightCorner) -- ++(0,-\H);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If someone has an explanation, I would still take it though!

Comment: A short explanation is that the TikZ parser looks for key symbols to decide what to do next. The main parser has very limited capability to handle macros, whereas the coordinate parser is more sophisticated. Without the parenthesis you are asking the main parser to handle the call to directlua, but with the parenthesis it knows you are specifying a coordinate so hands control over to the coordinate parser before it sees that call.